Is the convergence speed of local time in Markov processes a continuum.
By theorem 3.12 (p. 427) in the book Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion by Revuz and Yor, they claim that for an Harris recurrent Markov process $X$ with invariant measure $\mu$, and two functions $f$ and $g$ with $\int g\,\mathrm{d}\mu>0$, then
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^t f(X_s)\mathrm{d}s}{\int_0^t g(X_s)\mathrm{d}s}=\frac{\int f(x)\mathrm{d}\mu(x)}{\int g(x)\mathrm{d}\mu(x)}
$$
almost surely (sometimes called the quotient limit theorem). On the next page, they mention that if $X$ is positive Harris (see here for a definition), then constant functions are integrable meaning that additive functions increase like $t$. Now from my understanding, the growth with speed $t$ has an if and only if relation to positive Harris recurrence, so that when the process if not positice Harris recurrent, then the growth $h(t)=t^{\rho}$ for some $\rho\in[0,1]$ is so that $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{h(t)}=\infty$.
My question is if the spectrum of convergence is continuous? That is, for every $\rho\in(0,1)$, does there exist a Markov process $X$ such that the speed of convergence for additive functions is $t^\rho$?
